# How to write a customed insert query?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm inserting comma separated data into database from the java code.one of the variable contains appended strings with comma separated. i.e.,
String e_tag_postion_text="Ericsson,+university challenge".so I'm getting comma values in one row.

comma data

I want to insert the data in following formate.

each comma as separate row.with same id

Comment: yeah ! i'm inserting a string variable from java code by appending a comma into my database.now i want to insert as second pic formate.A insert query that inserts data as in pic 2 formate.can it possible ?@– wingedpanther

Comment: i'm trying same in all the tagged dbs. @ wingedpanther

Comment: tagging with the respective tech is good practice while asking a question but you should also mention in the question for simplicity of understanding the question instead of figuring it out from tags.

Comment: Don’t worry about duplicates,i will handle them.I'm using normal insert query.  insert into table_name values(' tweet_id','hashtag_name'); from the programming.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question properly, you can try something like below in PostgreSQL

```
create table t (id int,val text)

insert into t select 1232,unnest('{a,b}'::text[] )
```

and

```
select * from t
```

result

```
id   val 
---- --- 
1232 a   
1232 b
```

*OR*

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (
     133131313
    ,regexp_split_to_table('ericsson,universitychallenge', ',')
    );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497439/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-a-users-pkey-detail-key-a-nam                                   can you help me in finding the solution to this question @wingedpanther

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `postgresql` , Check if this works. Not tested .

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (tweet_id, e_hashtags_position0_text)    
SELECT table.tweet_id ,
   regexp_split_to_table(table.e_hashtags_position0_text, E',') as e_hashtags_position0_text
FROM table
;
```

Comment: yeah ! can I use insert in the place of select ?

Comment: @DilipBobby add Insert . Edited

Comment: side note: If the already has comma separated values then its better to update with `regexp_split_to_table` than insert because you can avoid duplicates