# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "A_users_pkey" Detail: Key (A_name)=(1) already exists

Tags: java, jdbc, psql

I'm trying to insert a string Value with comma separators and it works fine

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (133141214,regexp_split_to_table('rock,jackel', ','));
```

but my table has pkey Constraint to user name.When I Try to insert another String Value as follow

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (144141214,regexp_split_to_table('rock,raffel', ','));
```

My query has new value raffel in it.that raffel should enter into table but because of pkey the query is failing and saying 
`Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "A_users_pkey" Detail: Key (rock_name)=(1) already exists.`

How solve this and insert Raffel into table?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hello as I understand from your question, you are trying to insert 2 rows with only one INSERT statement.

The solution should be either to use **two** `INSERT` statements or to change your statement:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (regexp_split_to_table('144141214,144141215', ',')::bigint,regexp_split_to_table('rock,raffel', ','));
```

But I don't understand why would you be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Getting the error  :  INSERT INTO userdata VALUES (regexp_split_to_table('144141214,144141219', ',')::bigint,regexp_split_to_table('rock,locktherock', ','));
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "userdata_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (userfullname)=(rock) already exists.

Comment: Im getting a string value with comma separated  eg:String v="king,long,bang"; Now i'm trying to insert the values in different cloumns by using regex. my query works fine with out any pkey.When keep a pkey and try to insert the getting the error.Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: This sounds like you already have a row with a 'rock' "userfullname" or maybe that you are getting duplicate values in your String v="king,long,rock, john, rock".

I still don't understand why you are doing this at the query level, and not performing several INSERTs to the database.

Comment: can you give me an idea on giving several INSERTs to the database when i get a string v="king,long,rock, john"

Comment: If you are using java:

String v="king,long,bang";
for(String user:v.split(",")){
    /*Do your insert statements for each user*/
}